# A function is given. Determine the average rate of change of the function between the given values of the variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(t) = \frac {7}{t}$;

$t = a, $

$t = a + h$

I tried using the formula (change in y / change in x) and got $\frac {a^2+ah}{-7}$

It's been a while since I've done these problems (reviewing) so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $f'$ the rate of change? The average would be $\frac1h\int_{a}^{a+h} f'(t) \mathrm d t$.

Comment: I'm not sure we even learned that in our class... so I don't think so?

Comment: I get $\frac{-7}{a^2 + ah}$ instead. Please ignore my last comment.

Comment: let me try it again and see if I get the same answer as you this time

Comment: You were right, idk why I had it flipped the first time. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average rate of change on the interval $[a, a+h]$ is given by 
$$\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}f'(t)dt=\frac{-7}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\frac{1}{t^2}dt=\frac{-7}{a(a+h)}$$